# (DHTMLX Grid) Grouping show/hide column checkboxes

Tags: dhtmlx

So I have a treegrid, and I want users to be able to not only show and hide columns, I want them to be able to show and hide columns in bulk. Right now, I'm using `mygrid.enableHeaderMenu()` in order to allow the users to show and hide columns. However, I have about 50 columns, and need to give them the ability to show/hide columns in bulk.

For example, a sample of my columns would be:

- foo
- bar
- baz
- unrelated

I want users to be able to show/hide the foo, bar, and baz columns using one checkbox, as well as be able to show/hide each column separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up modifying the `enableHeaderMenu` function and adding the grouping mechanism in there.

To clarify, I used the source code in dhtmlxgrid_hmenu and created my own functions based off of that code. The actual grouping is done in `_createHContext`. To have it so that the checkbox for the group enabled or disabled grouping for the entire group, I copied the code for `applyHideFunction`, named it something else, and had that code apply `setColumnHidden` to all of the checkboxes in that group.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way seems to add your own context menu to the header, and call a needed functionality in the item clicking.
In case of using the dhtmlxMenu you may use:

```
 menu = new dhtmlXMenuObject();
 menu.renderAsContextMenu();

 mygrid.hdrBox.id = "gridHeader";
 menu.addContextZone("gridHeader");
```

Here is the tutorial about the dhtmlxMenu component:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/menu__index.html